# VB.Net Regex - I search a Pattern

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I am searching a Pattern for Regex that Matches every single letter in a String.

I have following Strings:

Given string --> wanted string

```
 - 225S225M --> SM
 - 225S225M225L --> SML
```

Please, can anyone help me? 
I want to have every single letter in the string with one Pattern.

Comment: What have you tried?  Sounds like you shoudl try a regular expression tool.  Of course matching only letters is a trivial regular expression.

Comment: I tried many things. I just read about Regex today, so I'm very new with this. But Steve got me the correct Answer. Thanks!

Comment: Google knows a lot of things, but it doesn't know how to create a trivial "only letter" expression with. So i asked you.

Comment: You are expected to at least attempt something. A little research on .NET regular expressions likely would have allowed you to come up with a solution yourself.  Please note a RegEx has a performance cost.  You might be better off just using `String.Replace` instead.  Compare the two, see which one, is actually faster.

Comment: I found a regular expression your looking  for by just reading the MSDN article on Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will simply remove any non numeric characters and gives your back all the remainder of your string

```
 Dim result = Regex.Replace(second, "[0-9]", "")
 Console.WriteLine(result)
```